# Printing 115 as 1.15 in Java

Tags: java

I am attempting to make this for loop look as if it is preforming exact arithmetic, but i'm not quite sure how to print out my int (ex. 115) as a "fake" double (ex. 1.15) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
for(int i = 115; i<350; i+=15)
{
  System.out.print(i);
  //possibly printf? I'm not very familiar with the method
}//for
```

Comment: double num = (double) i/100.0;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in this simple way.

```
System.out.print(i/100.0); // This will print 1.15, 1.3
```

But if you want to print 2 digits after the decimal, you'll need to do this.

```
System.out.printf("%.2f",i/100.0);  // This will print 1.15, 1.30
```

Comment: Close, but not quite what I wanted. When converting the i to a double by dividing it by 100.0, by the 4th time through the loop the round off error gets to be to great, meaning it shows up in the print statement.

Edit: Refreshed, sorry. Thank you for the help. Printf is a strange method to me....

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
  for(int i = 115; i<350; i+=15)
  {
      System.out.printf("%d.%02d%n", i / 100, i % 100);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is probably about money, I'd suggest using [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Don't do floating point operations on monetary values as rounding errors are inevitable in the long run, although they might not appear in this particular case, using `printf`. An accurate solution to your problem is this:

```
for (int i = 115; i < 350; i += 15) {
  System.out.println(new BigDecimal(i).movePointLeft(2));
}
```